# Route and nested route animation framer motion + react is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

got this problem when animating nested route inside a Parent component the parent will be unmounted and mounted again and the animation restart i need to block re rendering of the parent component here is my code in codesanbox . happy coding everyone
new Link [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-andras-z71o3)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Route, Switch, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import Home from "./component/home";
import OtherComponent from "./component/othercomoponent";
import ComponentWithNestedRoute from "./component/componentwithnestedroute";
export default function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="nav-container">
        <p>
          <Link to="/home">home</Link>
        </p>
        <p>
          <Link to="/ComponentWithNestedRoute">
            Component With nested route
          </Link>
        </p>
        <p>
          <Link to="/otherComponent">Other Component</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter initial={false}>
        <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route path={`/home`}>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/otherComponent"}>
            <OtherComponent />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/ComponentWithNestedRoute"}>
            <ComponentWithNestedRoute />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the nested Component  is like this each time when i click on a route the component will unmout and mount again and the animation of the nested component is repeated i want my nested never rerender again when my route is like /ComponentWithNestedRoute/:nested it is only the child component that rerender and restart the animation

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import Nested1 from "./Nested1";
import Nested2 from "./Nested2";
const containerVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      duration: 0.25,
      when: "beforeChildren"
    }
  },
  exit: {
    opacity: 0,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration: 1
    }
  }
};
class ComponentWithNestedRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location);
    return (
      <motion.div
        variants={containerVariants}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="visible"
        exit="exit"
        className="nestedComponent"
      >
        <p>
          <Link to={`${this.props.match.path}/nested1`}>Nested1</Link>
        </p>
        <p>
          <Link to={`${this.props.match.path}/nested2`}>Nested2</Link>
        </p>

        <div className="route-nested-wrapper">
          
            <Switch>
              <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/nested1`}>
                <Nested1 />
              </Route>
              <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/nested2`}>
                <Nested2 />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
     
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ComponentWithNestedRoute);
```

hope this is clear. happy coding again

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of the relevant code?

Comment: sorry i dont know how the code was completly removed from sanbox hereis a new link https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-andras-z71o3

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include an actual example code snippet here in your question, this way the relevant details stay in SO with the question as external links tend to decay over time.

Comment: ok i edit the question . thanks anyway for your time